# React setState async cause the delay of dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to made a dropdown with default value.

So, for example, it shows "Year" at the beginning, after clicking user should see 1987 as default value.

So I had this.setState to manipulate default value of dropdown.

I went well on desktop and android phone.

But when I used iPhone, either Chrome and Safari doesn't work well.(I shows Year at the first click, and after click again it shows 1987)

```
class MobileBind extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      birthYear: '',
      defaultYear: true,
    };


  }

  render() {
    const {
      birthYear,
   } = this.state;

    const createNumberSet = (min = 0, max = 10) => {
      if (min > max)
        return [];

      return Array(max - min + 1)
        .fill(min)
        .map((value, index) => value + index)
        .filter(value => value >= min);
    };

    const currentYear = moment().year();
    const years = createNumberSet(currentYear - 100, currentYear);
    const months = createNumberSet(1, 12);
    const days = createNumberSet(1, 31);

    return (
             <div className={style['birth-date-input']} style={{ margin: 0 }}>
                <FormControl>
                  <Select name="birthYear"
                    defaultValue={birthYear}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    onClick={this.handleDefalutYear}
                    native>
                    {
                      [
                      <option key="birthYear-default" value="" disabled >
    Year</option>,
                      ...(years || []).map(value => <option key={`birthYear-${value}`} value={value} >{value}</option>)
                      ]
                    }
                  </Select>
                </FormControl>
              </div>

  }


  handleChange = event => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }

  handleDefalutYear = () => {
      this.setState({defaultYear:false});
  }
```

I hope that default value can be changed with no delay(with one click!`)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Posting isolated snippets makes it more difficult to understand how the code works (and therefore more difficult to help).

Comment: can you show the whole component ?

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for reminding! I post whole js file, hope it works!!

Comment: @AlexandrZavalii I edited the content, thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `defaultValue` is for seeding uncontrolled components. Since you're controlling the component (you have an `onChange` and you're setting the `value` to state), pass `birthYear` to the `value` prop, not `defaultValue`.

Comment: Thanks for promptly reply. But my question is when I click the Year and drop down the first show default item will be "Year", not the number I want.   You can refer to this video: https://youtu.be/4G5awS1tiNs     This is the one I used value before, but still didn't work

Comment: Happy to help. Are you missing any code in the above example? I'm not seeing how you're passing in the default year. I see your onClick method but that value doesn't appear to be used anywhere so I suspect there is code missing.